# Are #include " <> " and #include < "" > valid file inclusions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is nitpicky, probably without any practical use. I am just curious...

From the C++20 working draft (n4861), header names are defined as:

```
(5.8)
header-name:
    < h-char-sequence >
    " q-char-sequence "
h-char-sequence :
    h-char
    h-char-sequence h-char
h-char:
    any member of the source character set except new-line and >
q-char-sequence :
    q-char
    q-char-sequence q-char
q-char:
    any member of the source character set except new-line and "
```

where the "source character set" is defined as:

```
(5.3.1) The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing
horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:9
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’
```

and Source file inclusions are defined as:

```
(15.3.2) A preprocessing directive of the form
    # include < h-char-sequence > new-line
    ...

(15.3.3) A preprocessing directive of the form
    # include " q-char-sequence " new-line
    ...
```

As I understand it, this means that the both include directives `#include " <> "` and `#include < "" >` are perfectly valid, one following the `h-char-sequence`, the other following the `q-char-sequence`.

This however seems rather strange and bizarre to me. I tried creating a header file named `<>` in visual studio which (IMHO kind of sanely) forbid this, informing me that no such header file may be created as both chars `<` and `>` are forbidden.

Strictly speaking, is visual studio following the Standard in this regard or am I overlooking something? Are both header names valid or invalid? If invalid, which section of the standard forbids this? Also, as the definitions of source file inclusions contain a space, is `#include <iostream>` even valid?

Comment: If Visual Studio can create a header file with a name containing '<', '>' and '"' depends on the filesystem and OS limitations. That has nothing to do with what the C++ standard allows.

Comment: Windows filename limitations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Slightly further down, you'll find text similar to the below (taken from the C99 standard):

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or
>   more letters or digits (as defined in 5.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single letter.
>   The first character shall be a letter. The implementation may ignore the distinctions of
>   alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the
>   period.

This has been unchanged pretty much since C99 and probably before.  So an implementation is allowed to reject include directive with odd characters in the file name (such as `"` or `<`), but is not required to.